# Vector C++ , whats wrong with getting the 2nd element of vector

Tags: c++

I have a vector which is of the code

```
Vector<Vehicle> list
Vehicle *v1;
```

I did the following

```
string inVehicle;

cout << "Enter Vehicle Type";
cin >> inVehicle;

*v1 = new Vehicle;
v1->setName(inVehicle);
```

so I do another code to

```
cout << v1[0].getName() << endl;
```

The result is okay, but if I add another value, as my cin Enter vehicle type is a switch case with while infinite till user key 5 to exit from program, it will keep working.

So I enter my 2nd entry, but when I try

```
cout << v1[1].getName() << endl;
```

The second record, it doesnt work. IT is blank, but if I cout v1.size() , it display as 2

How do I get the 2nd element record normally and working?

Comment: Your code is inconsistent. Is `v1` supposed to be a vector of vehicles, a pointer to vehicle, an array of vehicles, or just a vehicle?

Comment: Your could won't compile, by the way, but I assume you have copied something.

Answer (score 4):

v1 isn't a vector, nor an array but just a pointer that has been allocated to a single object. therefore `v1[1]` is not a valid object.

You should possibly not use `new` at all, if you want to use vector. (which is vector, not Vector)

```
std::vector<Vehicle> list;
list.push_back( Vehicle() );
list.back().setName( inVehicle );
```

You must be aware that your Vehicle objects will need to be copyable, default constructable and assignable.

From your previous question though it appears Vehicle is actually a base class. Therefore you would need a vector of pointers. If `shared_ptr` is not available to you (and I assume `unique_ptr` is not) you will have to use `new` to create the actual underlying class. `Vehicle` will need to have a virtual destructor and you will need to take care of deleting the objects later as `std::vector` will not delete your pointers for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem has to do with this part of the program:

```
cout << "Enter Vehicle Type";
cin >> inVehicle;
```

Are you entering a whole sentence? If you do, then the remaining part after the first space will be stored in the input buffer, and the second time the loop won't work.

Try the following:

```
cout << "Enter Vehicle Type";
getline( cin, inVehicle );
```

You'll have to #include utility. Also, don't forget to:

```
v1->setName(inVehicle);
list.push_back( v1 );
```

However, the definition of your vector is wrong, should be:

```
vector<Vehicle *> list;
```

And don't forget to create a new object before adding it to the vector:

```
v1 = new Vehicle;
v1->setName(inVehicle);
list.push_back( v1 );
```

Hope this helps.